# Sencha scroll bug android 2.3.5

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

After switching production mode on sencha touch 2 scroll seemed to nearly die on android 2 3 5 device, though on iphone/ipad everything works fine, any ideas?
im using Ext.NestedList

scroll:'vertical',
 fullscreen:true,

thanks

```
Ext.define('front.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
require: ["Ext.data.proxy.SQL", "Ext.field.Search", "Ext.NestedList", "Ext.data.Store"],
config: {
    fields: ['text'],
    scrollable: {
        direction: 'vertical'
    }

},
listeners:{
    intialize:function(){
    }
 }
 });

 treestore = Ext.create("Ext.NestedList", {
    fullscreen: true,
    scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical'
        },
    updateTitleText :false,
    useTitleAsBackText: false,
    defaultBackButtonText : null,
    backText: '<div class="backtext"></div>',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    useToolbar:true,
    id: 'mainPanel',
    /*listConfig:{
        itemTpl:'<div class="nav-element"><span style="" class="txt">{name}</span><span class="calc">'+f_count+'</span></div>'
    },*/
    title: '<div class="titleimg"></div>',
    displayField: 'title',
    store: {
        storeId:'ms',
        type: 'tree',
        id: 'ListCard',
        fields: [
            'title','code','name','c_count',
            {name: 'leaf', defaultValue: true}
        ],

        root: {
            leaf: false
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://now-yakutsk.stairwaysoft.net/frontmodel/catlist.php?f_count='+f_count,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'cat'
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: do you mean `scrollable` property right?. scroll does not more exist in Sencha 2.x.x

Comment: thanx,yes. a meant it. but what can be done to implement scroll.

Comment: post a working snippet of your code in the question.we can help you better if we can see the issue

Comment: find out that scroll is not suported in native browser and in bulid apk installed, though UC Browser it works well